# MySQL starts refusing connections when I start my game server

Tags: mysql, node.js, ubuntu

MySQL works fine until I start my game server. When I start my game server, I get the error "Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306"

If I run the webserver after running the game server, I will get that error as well, but if I run the webserver first, it works fine UNTIL I run the game server.

Similarly if I do mysql -u root -p and try to log in after I start the game server I get the error

' Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' '

I can literally use mysql -u root -p up until I get the first error message from the game server. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: So where is the code in your game server that connects to MySQL?

Comment: We need more information to help you here.